# Get array key does not work with Session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, array-key

I am using a Session Array on an script I designed a while back. Recently, when
modifying this working script, I ran into this error:

```
$CategoryId = key($_SESSION['StoreCategory'][$index]);
```

Returns an error:

> Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Is there an alternative way to get the Key of a Session Array?

Comment: Structure of `$_SESSION['StoreCategory']`?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['StoreCategory'][$index]);` ?

Comment: $_SESSION['StoreCategory'] clearly doesn't have the structure you expect. The first step, before Stackoverflow, is to var_dump it.

Comment: use var_dump to see structure and I think you have to test key existance before use key() function 
$CategoryId = (isset($_SESSION['StoreCategory'][$index]))?key($_SESSION['StoreCategory'][$index]):'';

Comment: [12124334] 'CategoryName'

Comment: As I said I designed this a while back...the array works just fine. Anyone else want to downarrow this question?

Answer (score 1):

`key()` method would give the key of the current element of the array, so the argument for this method should be an array.

If you are looking for all the keys of an array you can use `array_keys`.
Refer this for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php